# translateY of form hides div under it and I can't move it to display after the form

Tags: css, transform, translate-animation

I need to move a form with `translateY()`.

However, I have the issue that if there are any `div`s in the way of the form on Y axis, the form hides the `div` and I can't get it from under the form to display it after the form.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

```css
.positions {
  /* div which is on the way of translateY() of the form */
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#views-exposed-form-membership-directory-block-1 {
  /* form */
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  transform: translateY(-101%);
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could create a snippet with a minimum example of this behaviour?

Comment: Is that your code exactly? Because it looks like your commenting wrongly here in css

Comment: Oooh that's a good point. I edited them to make them actual CSS comments for the snippet (as I had assumed that was for our benefit). @Belial were those comments in your original CSS?

Comment: No, this comments I have only here.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the z-axis position on a page with the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property.

If you wish to ensure that the `div` ends up *above* the `form`, give it a higher `z-index` value. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
.positions {
  z-index: 1000;
}

#views-exposed-form-membership-directory-block-1 {
  z-index: 500;
}
```

I've set them to `1000` and `500` as the higher the number, the higher they will be in the z-axis (501 will appear above 500). I don't know how many divs with the `.positions` class you'll have, so I left a buffer of 500. If you only have one div, you can get away with `101` for the `div` and `100` for the `form`.